# How to limit the return results using MDX query

Tags: mdx

I am using `MDX` query to limit the huge results from my query using the following but it doesn't work. My intention is to limit the result to 10 only to reduce the loads

```
SELECT {[Measures].[activityduration]} ON COLUMNS,
       {([rig], 10)} ON ROWS 
FROM activityhours
```

The error says:

```
The following is not a valid MDX query: No function matches signature '(<Dimension>, <Numeric Expression>)'
```

Can anybody helps?

Answer (score 4):

If you mean limit to 10 rows of `rig`(since you talked about huge number of records), then below should help:

```
SELECT {[Measures].[activityduration]} ON COLUMNS,
       TOPCOUNT([rig], 10) ON ROWS 
FROM activityhours
```

It would be first 10 values from `[rig]` in natural order.

Answer (score 0):

What does "limit the result to 10" mean exactly? Limit to 10 rows, or do you want to filter `[rig]` somehow based on 10?

I've guessed you just want members of `[rig]` where `[Measures].[activityduration]` is equal to 10:

```
 SELECT {[Measures].[activityduration]} ON COLUMNS,
       [rig] 
         HAVING Measures].[activityduration] = 10 
          ON ROWS 
FROM activityhours;
```

Comment: I want to limit query result to 10 rows only to show on the output